# How To Access File Inside Jar File

Tags: java, maven, file, jar, classloader

I have the following code:

```
URI uri = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("test.csv").toURI();
```

Where it points to a CSV file in:

`git/Development/project/src/main/resources`

And this works perfectly fine when I run this as a Java application inside of Eclipse. However, when I do:

```
mvn package
java -jar project-*.jar
```

I get a **NullPointerException**.

I looked inside the jar and that file is located at:

`BOOT-INF/classes`

What is the correct way to access this CSV file?

Comment: You should go via `class.getResourcesAsStream("/test.csv");` and use the input stream...

Comment: @khmarbaise Even if all I ultimately want is the URI? Ultimately I want to be able to pass the URI to java.nio.file.Files.newBufferedReader(uri) which will return a java.io.Reader.

Comment: First based on the mentioned parts like `BOOT-INF/classes` you are in a spring boot app..the question is why do you need to load a resources yourself ? Why not using spring boot mechanisms? Apart from that have you tested it?

Comment: You can use a BufferedReader with an InputStream, just wrap the stream in an InputStreamReader

Comment: You *cannot* use Files.newBufferedReader, because a jar entry is not a separate file.  As others have said, use `new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(MyApplication.class.getResourceAsStream("/test.csv"), StandardCharsets.UTF_8))`.

Comment: Ah okay. Thanks guys. That worked. One of you guys should post that as an actual answer so I can mark it as such and give you credit for it.